# Rails 3.1 nested form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

Ive got the following scenario:

cmsasset model that is container for image using paperclip to upload and store, location model that can have attached cmsassets in a habtm join table approach

location accepts nested attributes for cmsassets here's the exact model code:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cmsassets, :allow_destroy => true
```

now when i try to use the following in my form code the nested form is not displayed:

```
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :target => @location %>
<p>Name<br />
<%= f.text_field :name %></p>
<p>Description<br />
<%= f.text_area :description %></p>
<p>Location Tags (Separated by a Comma)<br />
<%= f.text_field :tag_names %></p>
<%= render :partial => 'shared/contact_info_form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
<p>Splash Image:<br />
  <%= f.fields_for :cmsassets do |cmsasset_form| %>
  <%= cmsasset_form.number_field :client_id, :type => 'hidden', :value =>  session[:current_client] %>
  <p>Image Name:<br />
   <%= cmsasset_form.text_field :name %></p>
   <p>Description:<br />
   <%= cmsasset_form.text_field :description %></p>
   <p><%= cmsasset_form.file_field :attachment %><br />
   <%= cmsasset_form.text_field :cms_asset_type, :type => 'hidden', :value => 'Splash'  %></p>
  <% end %></p>
<p>Display Address:<br />
 <%= f.text_field :display_addr %></p>
 <p>Latitude<br />
  <%= f.number_field :latitude %></p>
 <p>Longitude<br />
  <%= f.number_field :longitude %></p>
 <p>Trigger Radius<br />
  <%= f.number_field :trigger_radius%></p>
  <p>Published >> <%= f.check_box :published %></p>
 <p>Expiration Date<br />
 <%= f.text_field :expiration_date %></p>
 <br />
 <%= f.submit "Save" %>
```

However, when I make cmsassets singular in the nested form call it renders but fails obviously because of the habtm data structure...

whats crazy is that this approach works using the nested_form gem, with the sole exception of paperclip causing a failure in this case because we use dynamic styles at the model level..

if anyone can shed some light on either of these issues i'd be very interested to hear some ideas!

Comment: OK, so one part of my issue I answered for myself which is the form not rendering on a new object creation. so i can take that off the table. however, the issue with paperclip still remains and that is far trickier. would still appreciate any input on that topic

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid HTML to write nested forms.

Try to place the upload form outside the main form.

Comment: can you be more specific? the rails guides indicate it's doable. are you saying do a partial?